# How to Use If-Else Condition to Display the Result

Tags: php, wordpress

WP developer,

I am using the below code to display h3 heading and post tags as title and it worked fine, however i eliminate it to work only on specific pages, it is now sitewide and used everywhere.
Example is here:

https://readnational.com/national-birds/

```
<h3 class="entry-title">                
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title()); ?>">
        <?php 
            $posttags = get_the_tags();
            if ($posttags) {
                echo '<ul class="symbolic">';
                echo '<li>' . $posttags[1]->name . '</li>';
                echo '</ul>'; 
            } 
        ?>          
    </a>            
</h3>
```

Now, i want to apply wordpres conditonal tag to run the code only for specific pages, I did it with conditaional tags using page IDs but its not working

```
<?php if(is_page([1364,211])){
<h3 class="entry-title">                
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title()); ?>">
        <?php 
            $posttags = get_the_tags();
            if ($posttags) {
                echo '<ul class="symbolic">';
                echo '<li>' . $posttags[1]->name . '</li>';
                echo '</ul>'; 
            } 
        ?>          
    </a> } <?php endif; ?>      
</h3>
```

I tried it a lot to use the code for specific pages using the conditional tags by Page IDs, but it is not working, also it is giving **syntax error**, So how to do it, kindly share full code properly,

Comment: What about this is supposed to be significantly different now, from what you asked a couple of hours earlier? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73553366/1427878

Comment: This actually appears to be the _fourth_ time you are asking about this now.

Comment: You should to close the initial php block with a closing tag in the same line: `?>`. Just as the code you copied from somewhere does in the `endif` block: an opening and a closing tag around the actual php code.

Comment: @arkascha No one is sharing full code with me that is the reasons i opened new question, kindly share the full code with me as my code have syntax error and not working.

Comment: @ChrisHaas kindly share full code, no one has yet shared the full code with me, share full code in this post what i have asked for, please thanks bundles

Comment: @CBroe yes, but no one is getting my point, this is the actual thing i want, kindly share the full code in this post what i have asked for,

Comment: We are not here to write your code for you. And if no one was getting your point - well then why hasn't the explanation of the problem _improved_ by now, why are you still asking the same thing in the very same way? _What_ about this did people not get then, in your opinion?

Comment: @John, as everyone is noting, focus this to one question. If you feel a need to start over, you can delete your previous questions, although that will unfortunately remove access to the comments from most people.

Comment: @ChrisHaas i deleted the previous posts, now kindly someone could help me here?

Comment: I think I did get your point. And I wrote in my comment what the issue is. We expect you to be able to understand what is explained to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has what's called "[Alternative syntax for control structures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)" and although a lot of people don't like it, I think it is really great for developers that might not be as comfortable in PHP as they are in HTML. It allows you you mentally separate your PHP and HTML in a clearer way, at least IMHO.

Rewriting your code with that in mind, and also introducing a little more escaping as well as a loop over the tags gives you this:

```php
<?php if (is_page([1364, 2011])): ?>
    <h3 class="entry-title">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e(get_the_title()); ?>">
            <?php if ($posttags = get_the_tags()) : ?>
                <ul class="symbolic">
                    <?php foreach ($posttags as $posttag): ?>
                        <li><?php esc_html_e($posttag->name); ?></li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
    </h3>
<?php endif; ?>
```

That loop I introduced might not be what you want, however, and you might literally want the second item from the tag array always. If that's the case, this version might be what you want.

```php
<?php if (is_page([1364, 2011])): ?>
    <h3 class="entry-title">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e(get_the_title()); ?>">
            <?php if ($posttags = get_the_tags()) : ?>
                <ul class="symbolic">
                    <li><?php esc_html_e($posttags[1]->name); ?></li>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
    </h3>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Millions of thanks you got my point and you solved my problem, you did the job what i want, the last code you shared is working fine, however, there is quit little issue, the code is work on one page but not on the other page, it is working on the page id 1364 link: https://readnational.com/national-birds/ but it does not work on the page ID 211 link: https://readnational.com/national-fruits/ you can see their source page too. Both IDs are added in the code but don't know why the other is not working. check the is_page([1364, 211])) in the code might it has any issue,

Comment: @John, that second page is `2011`, not `211`

Comment: i just put the array conditional tags and it start working on other pages too, Thanks your code is awesome, i am sharing now the full code with array conditional tag

Comment: that Oh my bad yes its now working, the array conditional is also good one.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if (is_page( array(1364, 2011) ) ) : ?>
    <h3 class="entry-title">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e(get_the_title()); ?>">
            <?php if ($posttags = get_the_tags()) : ?>
                <ul class="symbolic">
                    <li><?php esc_html_e($posttags[1]->name); ?></li>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
    </h3>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The array is working good to add as many pages id as we want, Thanks to @Chris Haas